# midiInGetNumDevs & midiOutGetNumDevs not updating properly

Tags: c#, midi, winmm

I am writing a C# application with hotplug support for Novation Launchpads, which are MIDI devices. I am using the `midi-dot-net` library, which uses the Win32API and `winmm.dll`'s functions, `midiInGetNumDevs` & `midiOutGetNumDevs`. Although for testing I am not using the `midi-dot-net` library.

This is my test code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        public static extern int midiInGetNumDevs();
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        public static extern int midiOutGetNumDevs();

    }

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] arg) {
        while (true) {
            Console.WriteLine("In '" + NativeMethods.midiInGetNumDevs() + "', Out '" + NativeMethods.midiOutGetNumDevs() + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

The results are as follows (I have 2 Launchpads to test with):

If I plug in a device, no matter what, the numbers shown do not change at all and the program does not seem to register a device has been plugged in.

If I unplug one of the launchpads, it decrements the number plugged in, BUT, only once. If I then unplug the second launchpad the number never changes.

This behaviour sounds suspiciously like what was described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2862818), however that is an update for Windows 8. While I am on a system that was upgraded using the Windows 10 built-in upgrade from Windows 8, the KB provides an updated `winmm.dll` of version `6.2.9200.16645` but the one on my system is version `10.0.10586.0`. I have tried downloading the suggested DLL version from a 3rd party site but using that DLL had no effect on the behaviour.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The audio stuff was rewritten yet again in Windows 10, and this appears to be one of those bugs that is likely to be reintroduced. Report it to Microsoft.

Comment: @CL., would using the 'patched' DLL from Windows 8, version 6.2... not fix it though if that were the case? Or might the issue be outside of the winmm.dll file?

Comment: It's unlikely that you'll be able to use a DLL from the wrong version.

Comment: Crap, running into this as well, did you report to Microsoft or did you find a solution? Seems that Microsoft still hasn't fixed it after more than half a year!

Comment: No I never did find a solution, currently my program has to restart itself when it detects a device has been physically plugged in or unplugged.